# java generics; force type of parameter object for return object

Tags: java, generics, types, wildcard

```
public class Main<T> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wrapper<Double> wrapper = new Wrapper<>(0.0d);
        method(wrapper);
    }

    public static Wrapper<?> method(Wrapper<?> wrapper) {
        Wrapper<?> wrapper2 = new Wrapper<>(1);
        return wrapper2;
    }
}

public class Wrapper<T extends Number> {
    private final T member;

    public Wrapper(T member) {
        this.member = member;
    }
}
```

`Wrapper` `wrapper` has Type `Double`. It is then passed to `method()`, which first makes `wrapper2` with Type `Integer` and returns it.

Is there some way to force `wrapper2` to have the same Type as the parameter `Wrapper` `wrapper`, i.e. that `wrapper2` must have Type `Double`?

Comment: Is this what you need? `public static <T extends Number> Wrapper<T> method(Wrapper<T> wrapper)`?

Comment: You want a generic method.

Comment: It gives me this exception: Uncompilable source code - The type of <T>Wrapper(T) is erroneous

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: You can't pass `1`, since you don't know what type your parameter is.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can't return a `Wrapper<Integer>` if you don't know what `T` is.

Comment: But you also cannot return a `Wrapper<Double>`.

Comment: That's correct. You can only return `Wrapper<T>`.